# Does AWS CDK support multiple languagues within a project?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

If I am developing an app using the AWS CDK, can I use one language for the infrastructure and a separate language for my lambda code?

For example, can I create buckets, rules, lambdas etc. with typescript, but then deploy python code within the lambda? Especially considering I may need to pass a newly created bucket to the python code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can certainly do this.  If you take a look at the "serverless" examples for CDK, you'll see that for all of the supported languages the Lambda that is created is built in Node.  The [Java examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/serverless_example.html#java), for example, includes ways to build with the Java CDK and, inside of the project, include the JavaScript code.  Python and C# are very similar.

Comment: I know I can deploy code in a different language, but if I need to reference infrastructure in that code, is that possible?  For example, if I have python code being deployed with a lambda, and within the code it needs to reference a bucket that is being created in typescript, am I able to do that?

Comment: nm - I see now that I can put environment variables when I build the lambda, then access that via my lambda python code.  Thanks!